# How to create infusionsoft plugins that will communicate with mongoosemetrics APIs?

Tags: php, web-services, api, infusionsoft

I am a senior PHP developer, but I'm newbie with Infusionsoft. My client has the requirements below:

1. Create a plugin in Infusionsoft to trigger an event at the time of affiliate registration with a affiliate traceable phone number via Mongoose API.
2. Create a plugin in Infusionsoft to trigger an event at the time of affiliate login which will send a affiliate traceable phone number via Mongoose Metrics API and send a response with call details/statistics to the Infusionsoft server.

I actually do not where and how to create a plugin in Infusionsoft and how to call Mongoose Metrics API in it.

**Can anybody please give me step-by-step info if possible so that I can work through this faster?**

Comment: @user2345543 have you checked this http://help.infusionsoft.com/developers/api-basics  ??

Comment: Yes, i had already gone through this things, but i didnt get understood that how to start creating plugins and how can i put that code to infusionsoft server??

Comment: @Chans where you want to implement the plugin wordpress/joomla/your own cms/framework ?? Although I never used this though but you can try some example try to modify the code and look for answer at thr support channels

Comment: @swapnesh: Actually i dont want to create a plugin for wordpress/joomla but for infusionsoft only. when any affiliate get registered in infusionsoft at the time that custom api should call and send a data to the another server using my api. is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a webform for your affiliates to signup you can have Infusionsoft send a POST with the information the affiliate used in the form to a script which would add the number to mongoose api.

If you are manually creating affiliates inside infusionsoft then there is no automatic listener to send the information, a post would have to be setup in an actionset and run manually on the affiliate's contact record. If you are not familiar with action sets you can read about them [here](http://ug.infusionsoft.com/article/AA-00861/0/What-is-an-action-set-Legacy.html)

As far as the second plugin there is no way to run an action when an affiliate logs in. You might be able to do some magic if you find a way to add HTML/Javascript to the affiliate login page and send that information to your server. However, that is a very ugly way to do it.